# text box validator for minimum length

Tags: asp.net, validation

```
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword" 
ErrorMessage="New Password is required." ToolTip="New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

How can I validate the text box to enter a value which length should be more than 8 and must contain 1 number and 1 uppercase letter.

Answer (score 6):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1" runat="server"    
ErrorMessage="Password length must be between 7 to 10 characters"
ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{7,10}$" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to your RequiredFieldValidator **add** a RegularExpressionValidator

For the regex pattern you can use this pattern:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

Must be at least 8 characters
Must contain at least one one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character
Valid special characters are -   @#$%^&+=

Technically you could use just the Regex validator but using multiples allows you to have different errors messages depending on a missing vs. simply incorrect password.

Comment: Yes, you should use multiple validators.
Here's mine for length alone:`^[\s\S]{6,}$`

Answer (score 3):

You should use two separate validators, one to check for length and the other to check for the minimum required characters (that way you get two separate error messages for each check).

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyPasswordField" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<!-- Add validator for minimum length requirement -->
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="MyPasswordField" ID="MyPassordMinLengthValidator" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{8,}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password must be at least 8 characters long."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<!-- Add validator for minimum required characters -->
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="MyPasswordField" ID="MyPassordRequiredCharacterValidator" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one number."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If you also need to validate the password for a maximum length as well, you can change the regex for the first validator to be as follows:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="MyPasswordField" ID="MyPassordMinMaxLengthValidator" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{8,40}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password must be between 8 and 40 characters long."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If you need to validate that at least one special character was present then you can use this regex for the second validation (at least one of the following characters: <space>@#$%^&?,;:_|{}=+-!.*()[]~):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="MyPasswordField" ID="MyPassordRequiredCharacterValidator" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&?,;:_|~{}=\+\-\!\.\*\(\)\[\] ]).+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use two validators: the `LenghtValidator` and the `RegularExpressionValidator`.

The advantage of having two validators is that you can have two error messages.

Comment: `LenghtValidator`? I don't see it in [Microsoft's list of validation controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)?